# Endpoint VPN error

Tags: macos, vpn

Cannot reinstall Endpoint.  Keep getting error: "Endpoint Security VPN build 860010008 is already installed on this computer".  How do I uninstall completely to do reinstall?

Comment: what specifically have you tried? version numbers and other things listed at [ask] will help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but since this is the only one I could find with this problem I'm writing what resolved the problem for me.

If you're getting this error, it means that there are files leftover in your system even after deleting the app that make the installer think that the app is still installed on the system.

On your terminal, run `/Library/Application\ Support/Checkpoint/Endpoint\ Connect/Uninstaller`. This should completely uninstall all related files and then you can do a fresh installation of the Endpoint Security package.